# class vs interface to describe object

Tags: typescript, class, oop, interface

What is the proper way to describe object in TypeScript (maybe not only in TypeScript). For example i have some get http request that returns me an object that has 2 params (name and id).
I see 3 ways to describe it.
The first is to create an interface

```
export interface MyObject {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}
```

The second way is to create a class

```
export class MyObject {
  public name: string;
  public id: number;
}
```

or the same class but with getters and setters

```
export class MyObject {
  private _name: string;
  private _id: number;

  public get name(): string {
    return this._name;
  }

  public set name(value: string) {
    this._name = value;
  }

  // similarly for id
}
```

So what is the most clear and proper way to do this. I mostly use interfaces to describe an object. But i've seen a lot of projects where object were described by classes, what are pros and cons of those 3 methods. Is there one most proper?

Comment: I prefer the interface, because it simply _describes_ an object, rather than a class which provides a template for _instantiating_ an object.

Comment: The third version doesn't compile. Private properties and setters/getters should have distinct names. Use `private _name: string` and `private _id: number` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example i have some get http request that returns me an object that has 2 params (name and id). I see 3 ways to describe it.

An HTTP request fetches a JSON string, which is then parsed.

## The dynamic way

The dynamic way is to simply use the object produced by the JSON parser. An `interface` is the right tool to describe it :

```
export interface MyObject {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}

// …
const result = JSON.parse(await fetch(…)) as MyObject;
```

## The heavy OOP way

Here, the JSON parser provides the same object as previously, but we prefer to create another one by instantiating a class:

```
export class MyObject {
  constructor(public name: string, public id: number) {
  }
}

// …
const { name, id } = JSON.parse(await fetch(…));
const result = new MyObject(name, id);
```

## The maxi verbose OOP way

Same thing with yet another an indirection using setters and getters :

```
export class MyObject {
  private _name: string;
  private _id: number;

  public get name(): string {
    return this._name;
  }

  public set name(value: string) {
    this._name = value;
  }

  public get id(): number {
    return this._id;
  }

  public set id(value: number) {
    this._id = value;
  }
}

// …
const { name, id } = JSON.parse(await fetch(…));
const result = new MyObject();
result.name = name;
result.id = id;
```